# Wordpress Pagination Only showing 2 pagess

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've set up a basic homepage to show 3 articles per page with pagination to navigate through these pages. At the moment it'll only show pagination for pages 1 & 2 and no more, even though I have 12 articles which result in 4 pages. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong here:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged'))? get_query_var('paged') : '1';

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'    => 2
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();

        include(locate_template('content-post.php' ));

    endwhile;
?>

<?php the_posts_pagination( array('mid_size' => 3) ); ?>
```

[image: Dummy posts]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**the_posts_pagination** use default WP query so it not work here. Can you please try below code:

```
<?php
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {$paged = get_query_var('page'); } else {$paged = 1; }

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'posts_per_page'    => 2
    );
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($wp_query -> have_posts()) : $wp_query -> the_post();
        include(locate_template('content-post.php' ));
    endwhile;


    the_posts_pagination( array('mid_size' => 3) );

    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $temp;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

**Code is tested in work perfect.**

Comment: So that gets the relevent amout of pagination links working, however any page beyond 2 goes straight to 404. E.g. `/page/2/` works fine but `/pages/3/` produces a 404.

Comment: Thanks but it's still the same, pagination works for pages 1-2 then 3 onwards 404.

Comment: in which page you are using above code? as here it working perfectlly

Comment: So I use it on home.php

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks alright to me. I was having the same issue, I resolved it by matching the `posts_per_page` with the `Blog pages show at most` field located in `Settings->Reading` in the admin dashboard

example:

`"posts_per_page" => 6` then `Blog pages show at most` should be also 6

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin [Click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/installation/)

and use this shortcode for pagination  `<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>`

and I use exact following loop for my project and its working.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args= array(
 'cat' => '',
 'orderby'=> 'date',
 'order'=> 'DESC',
 'paged' => $paged ,
 'posts_per_page' => 3
);
query_posts($args); 
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()):
    the_post();
  endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Please try it. Hope it will work for you also.

And If you are displaying your posts on home page, you need to replace

`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

with

```
<?php

if ( get_query_var('paged') ) 
    { 
        $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
    } 
else if ( get_query_var('page') ) 
    {
        $paged = get_query_var('page'); 
    }
    else 
    {
        $paged = 1; 
    }
```

Comment: That's great but it's still only showing 2 pages in the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; retrieves the data of the main query object but not for the custom one.
I found a solution here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops